C#.NET apply JMESPath query to native obejcts
Im looking for a way to use JMSEPath with native objects, so I pass a Dictionary or a List or combination of both. But no JSON string or Newtonsoft JToken/JObject, because I assume the latter actually are serialized.
I looked everywhere, even at the code of JmesPath.Net (too advanced for me unfortunately) and considered using C++ libraries. But seemingly no one has the use case to just apply the JMESPath query directly, without serializing it into a JSON string/JObject first, like you can do in python.
And no, I don't want to use LINQ because I can't use it anywhere else.
